# CLI: Increment a number in a string while keeping padded zeroes

Tags: regex, string, perl, sed, command-line

I currently use this perl command to increment the last number in a string:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)(?!.*\d+)/$1+1/e' <<< "abc123_00456.txt"
```

It outputs `abc123_457.txt`, while I want `abc123_00457.txt`.

I also want something like `99` to increment to `100`, though if that's too hard, `00` is also acceptable.

Some more examples of what I want:

```
09 -> 10
004 -> 005
```

I also want to be able to increment by any number (not just 1), so no `++`.

I do not want to use shell's builtins to accomplish this.

Comment: Tip: `(?!.*\d+)` can be simplified to `(?!.*\d)`, and it would be best to use `/s` since there's no reason to check for line feeds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)(?=\D*\z)/my $n = $1; ++$n/e' <<< "abc123_00456.txt"
```

The `++` operator [preserves the number of digits](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) when incrementing a string.

Alternatively:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)(?=\D*\z)/sprintf "%0*d", length($1), $1 + 1/e' <<< "abc123_00456.txt"
```

This lets you increment by more than just 1 (or perform other arithmetic operations).

`sprintf` `%d` formats an integer in decimal format. `0` means to pad the result with zeroes; `*` means the maximum field width is taken from the next argument instead of the format string itself. (E.g. `%05d` means "format a number by padding it with zeroes until it is at least 5 characters wide".)

Here we simply take the length of the original string of digits (`length($1)`) and use it as our field width. The number to format is `$1 + 1`. If it is shorter than the original string, `sprintf` automatically adds zeroes.

See also [`perldoc -f sprintf`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/sprintf).

Comment: This works, but I was hoping to be able to generalize the number incremented (not just 1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formatted string with `sprintf`:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/sprintf("%05d",$1+1)/e' <<< "abc123_00456.txt"
```

The 5 gives the width of your number, the 0 is the character used to pad the number.

For an unknow width, you can build dinamically the formatted string:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/sprintf("%0".length($1)."d",$1+1)/e' <<< "abc123_00456.txt"
```

Comment: The number of zeroes is not specific to 5.

Comment: @HappyFace: 5 is the width of the whole number, not the number of zeroes.

Comment: The width of the number is not a constant.

Comment: @HappyFace: Ok, and do you always increment by 1?

Comment: No, that is not a constant either, I set it via "${1:-1}".

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk -v n=17 'match($0,/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] sprintf("%0*d",length(a[2]),a[2]+n) a[3]} 1' <<< "abc123_00456.txt"
abc123_00473.txt
```

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -v n=17 'match($0,/[0-9]+\./){lgth=RLENGTH-1; tgt=substr($0,RSTART,lgth); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%0*d",lgth,tgt+n) substr($0,RSTART+lgth)} 1' <<< "abc123_00456.txt"
abc123_00473.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the number is at the beginning of the string, e.g. `00456.txt`.

Comment: Right but the number isn't at the beginning of the string (it's a simple tweak if it could be of course). It also won't work if the number is in exponent or floating point format but that's not what the OP has shown us as her sample input either.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed -E 's/^([^0-9]*([0-9]+[^0-9]+)*0*)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1$((\3+1))\4"/e' file
```